# Can I yank (copy) around a block comment in vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste, text-editor

One of my favorite things about vi(m)'s yank (i.e. copy) syntax is the ability to copy the entire contents of the current word, line, parens, code block, etc. using the `ya{something}` and `yi{something}` syntaxes

Examples for reference:

- word: `yaw`
- parens: `ya(`
- curly braces (without the braces): `yi{`
- XML/HTML tag: `yat`

So what I'm trying to figure out now is whether vim recognizes block comments as a yankable unit. I'm imagining something like `yac`. Is this standard? If not, is there a plugin or a mapping that someone's figured out?

Comment: I haven't used it but this sounds like it might be a use for https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Comment: I don't believe there is anything like `yac` in "standard" vim. The closest I've seen is just using `yap` (yank around paragraph/block).

Comment: @patrickvacek hmm ... that *almost* works, but if there's any code directly adjacent to the bottom of the comment block without a newline in between it will yank that as well. It's a good fallback though, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it's the best I'm aware of, other than going to the top of the block and doing something like `y5y` or however many lines there are. As you've suggested, it'd be great if there was a more intelligent way to detect that number automatically (and from any location with the block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, if you install a plugin, for example: https://github.com/glts/vim-textobj-comment

Comment: YW. I use it myself.